How can the Troxler effect be interpreted phenomenologically?
The Troxler effect, also known as Troxler fading, is a visual illusion that influences our perceptual experience. If one fixes their gaze on a specific point for a brief period, stimuli that remain static in the periphery of the visual field begin to fade and eventually disappear.

From a phenomenological perspective, it would be interesting to explore how an element that is given in perception can "disappear" within the very act of perceiving. How would this phenomenon be addressed in Husserl's philosophy?
Here, we would have a case, I believe, where the hyletic data change but also transform the noema: it shifts from "a set of circles" to "a circle orbiting a cross." I am particularly interested in understanding how a perception can go from being something to "nothing", i.e., from presence to absence. If you know of more examples like this, I would be delighted to hear about them!

Perception morphing or absence-in-presence phenomena is not rare and similar to even the static hyletic data such as  Rabbit–duck illusion introduced by Wittgenstein originated from psychologist Joseph Jastrow where we witness a shift in noematic constitution due to the noesistic act and wherefore shows the dependency of perception not merely on external input but on the internal structures of consciousness. Husserl interprets this in the context of temporal consciousness as immediate passed retention and anticipating protention...
